# Cannot create SSL connection with Vertx server and client

Tags: java, http, ssl, vert.x

I am trying to test an SSL connection between a Vertx HttpServer and HttpClient. Because I don't have any certificates, I created some self signed certificate like this:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias selfsigned -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -storepass pass -keysize 2048 -validity 360
```

I have generated a public certificate as such:

```
keytool -export -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -rfc -file public.cert
```

And then I

```
keytool -import -file public.cert -alias public -keystore trustStore.jks
```

Then I tried adding them as JksOptions to the Server and Client in any possible order I could imagine and all of them generate the same error on the client side:

> Future{cause=Failed to create SSL connection}

I don't understand what I do wrong and as much as I read about keystores and truststores, any combination didn't work for my program. If I set the client as `trustAll(true)`, the connection happens succesfully.

Here are the settings for the server and the client:

```
   HttpServerOptions httpServerOptions = new HttpServerOptions();
        JksOptions options = new JksOptions();
        options
            .setPassword("pass")
            .setPath("src/main/resources/file/keystore.jks");
        httpServerOptions
            .setSsl(true)
            .setKeyStoreOptions(options);

    HttpClientOptions httpClientOptions = new HttpClientOptions();
    JksOptions options = new JksOptions();
    options
        .setPassword("pass")
        .setPath("src/main/resources/file/trustStore.jks");
    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(httpClientOptions
            .setSsl(true)
            .setTrustStoreOptions(options)
    );
```

The code above appears in 2 separate Verticles and is run separately. What could be the issue?

- I have checked and the certificate does appear both in the keystore and truststore
- The CN = localhost, cause ultimately my client websocket does the following: `client.webSocket(8080, "127.0.0.1",...`
- I tried setting `.setVerifyHost(false)`, same result
- I have tried the solutions in the other questions and they didn't work

Comment: If you are going to use unsigned certificates than the only way to make this work is to add the conf you already suggested trustAll(true)

Comment: Ah so I cannot use self-signed certificates like this for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps needed to create self signed certificates and to use the in vertx.
Preparing keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias server-alias -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore keystore.jks

keytool -export -alias server-alias -storepass changeit -file server.cer -keystore keystore.jks

keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server-alias -file server.cer -keystore cacerts.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
```

Here is vertx code:

```
vertx.createHttpServer(new HttpServerOptions()
                .setSsl(true)
                .setKeyStoreOptions(new JksOptions().setPassword("changeit")
                        .setPath("keystore.jks")))
                .requestHandler(req -> req.response().end("Hello!"))
                .listen(9999, "127.0.0.1");

HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(new HttpClientOptions()
                .setVerifyHost(false)
                .setSsl(true)
                .setTrustStoreOptions(new JksOptions().setPassword("changeit")
                .setPath("keystore.jks")));
```

Comment: I have tried this. It doesn't really work if you want to create the Client and Server in separate Verticles because then the certificate won't be shared, unless you try really hard to share it with some toolkit global variables. I would add more details if I knew what else. The certificates are generated by keytool

Comment: I have updated the answer as I was not aware you had client and server in different apps/scopes

Comment: Adding verifyHosts(false) seems to have done the job. Thank you!. I assume it is needed because of the self signed certificates and their availability.